# How do you divide a number by a number from a index?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program is supposed to answer equations in the form ax = b

```
    a = input("What is the part with the variable? ")
    b = input("What is the answer? ")
    print('the equation is', a , '=', b)
    letter = a[-1]
    number = a[0:-1]
    answer = b /= number
    print(letter,"=",answer)
```

In line 6, I'm getting an invalid syntax error. How can do it to answer the equation?

Comment: Your syntax error is happening because python doesn't know what to do with 'b /= number'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = input("What is the part with the variable? ")
b = input("What is the answer? ")
print('the equation is', a , '=', b)
letter = a[-1]
number = a[0:-1]
answer =float(b)/float(number)
print(letter,"=",answer)
```

> What is the part with the variable? 25c
>
> What is the answer? 8
>
> the equation is 25c = 8
>
> c = 0.32

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution. Note, you need to change the type of your input from string (I used float for this, but integer should also work).

```
a = float(input("What is the part with the variable? "))
b = float(input("What is the answer? "))
print('the equation is',a,'* X =',b)

# solve the equation: aX = b for X
x = b/a

print("X =",x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is a better version of you code :
a = input("What is the part with the variable? ")
b = input("What is the left hand side of the equation? ")
print('the equation is {}x = {}'.format(a , b))
answer = float(b) /float(a) // convert the inputs to floats so it can accept mathematical operations 
print("x=",answer)
```